# Is it possible to recognise objects like cars with Spark Ar studio?

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I started working with Spark Ar recently and wanted to know if it is possible to recognise objects, specifically cars, and to animate filters around them. Is it possible and what's the best way to go about doing something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as of today. I recommend you to try out other tools, such as AR Kit and Google's AR Core for that.